# Posting apex code in blog

Tags: apex, blogger, wordpress

I know about [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/brushes/) but it does not support apex code.How you post salesforce code in Blogger or Wordpress?

Answer (score 2):

If you have Git Account you can create something called as a gist

Creating a Gist

[image]

Once you create a public gist ,you will get an embed link as shown below

[image]

> Use the Embed URL script in the blogger or wordpress .

Also Apex braces and indentations resemble same to Java so you can use syntax highlighter with plugins for java .

Comment: If using Embed URL,it does not show up.So I just follow the documentation here https://en.support.wordpress.com/gist/ ,which work perfectly fine.But because it pointing the URL, it will not available if I delete the code inside Git.I tried to use Syntaxhighlighter with Java but I always need to encode for this <> ex. <MyObject>.